What’s the point of the zig zag or backwards N hole pattern on some Nicholson aprons?

What’s the advantage of this pattern on the apron of a Nicholson/English/Joiner bench?

Backwards N? I don't know how you write your Ns but the above would generally be considered right way round ^_^

In general where you see a diagonal hole arrangement like this it is to space the holes closer together, vertically or horizontally, than would be possible (or strong enough, or considered strong enough) if they were in a straight line along that axis.
Here, I think one can see that if you spaced six holes in a straight line vertically the holes might be considered too close together but not by everyone; plus it's also dependent on apron thickness and species.
As a result, on an apron like this I think the arrangement is more to space a pattern of holes so that you maximise the potential reach of holdfasts1 across a range of vertical and horizontal positions without having to drill "too many" holes.
This same concern about drilling too many holes extends to workbench tops as well, the proffered theory being largely that it undermines strength2 rather than to save time/energy during the build — after all you drill holdfast or dog holes, however many there are, just the one time and then possibly make use of them for the rest of your life....

1 The primary workholding device on benches of any similar design, esp. those with no vice of any kind.
2 I think a lot of that is handwringing from weekend warriors who like to excessively armchair-theorise, but to be fair I have seen it expressed by seasoned hands and pros too. But again, specifics matter and thickness and material are very much important factors.
